# Opening a mvc application from classic asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, response.redirect

I am having a fully developed MVC Application having login functionality using custom membership. 
My client is having a classic asp.net application, must be having its own login functionality(Don't have exact details of login may be simple database user allowed to login or windows authentication)

Client application will have a button, clicking on which should redirect to my mvc app/somecontroller/someaction

I have tried normal coding as below, but app does not redirect.

```
protected void btnConfig_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string mywebUrl = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mywebUrl"];
            //It is like localhost:9108

            /* I have tried setting cookie same way as it is set in my mvc app */

            //string cookiedata = "admin";
            //string userData = string.Empty;
            //var expiretime = DateTime.Now.Add(FormsAuthentication.Timeout);
            //FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, cookiedata, DateTime.Now, expiretime, false, userData);
            //string encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);
            //HttpCookie formAuthCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket);
            //Response.Cookies.Add(formAuthCookie);

            Response.Redirect(mywebUrl + "/Home/Index", true);
        }
```

Comment: As far as I am aware you can't redirect from one application to another unless they are managed by the same application pool or you provide some means to transfer the session data over and create a session on the other site. Just open another browser window with the URL if you just want to display the site... but you can't redirect a response!

Comment: What do you mean by "app does not redirect"? What exactly happens?

Comment: Do you have schema specified in your mywebUrl setting?

Comment: @Wheels73 I have tried hosting both the applications in my local IIS on same pool, still same behavior.

Comment: @JustAndrei -  "app does not redirect"? means Page does not redirect. In Network Tab I can see my request got cancelled.

Comment: @Vandita - Try changing the return type from void to ActionResult then change to "return Redirect(mywebUrl + "/Home/Index", true);"

Comment: @Vandita - Where is that button click code? That looks like winforms / asp.net not MVC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This button click code is in asp.net application from where I want to open MVC Application.
I was making a very silly mistake.

```
    protected void btnConfig_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("http://localhost:5555" + "/Home/Index");
        // I was missing http:// in my url
    }
```

Comment: That's what I asked you: "Do you have schema specified in your mywebUrl setting?"